# How to multiply Celsius and kilograms?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

I have something like this:

$$\frac{0.04\,\text{kg} \times 90\,^{\circ}\text{C}  +  0.06\,\text{kg} \times 50\,^{\circ}\text{C}}{0.1\,\text{kg}} = T_k$$

Where $T_k$ is a temperature, in Celsius. But I have no idea how to multiply Celsius times kilograms. How do I do it?

Comment: First, you have to convert celsius to kelvin. Next, you just multiply normally, like so: $0.04\mathrm{kg}*363\mathrm{K}=14.52\mathrm{kg-K}$. When you divide $\mathrm{kg-K}$ by $\mathrm{kg}$, the kilograms cancel and you are left with Kelvins.

Comment: @Greg: Thank you. I have one more question - why is it `kg - K`? Why is there a minus sign? Will there always be minus when multiplying `kg` and `K`?

Comment: There's no need for conversion to kelvin. Think it through @ojek, are you *really* multiplying kilograms and centigrades here? Try to rearrange your expression so it becomes clear to you that the right hand side does indeed have the dimensions of temperature.

Comment: @Wouter: Okay I could do that, but I asked this question just out of curiosity, how to multiply these two.

Comment: @Greg: I ended up with `(14.52kg - K + 19.38kg - K) / 0,1kg` which gives me `(33.9kg - K - K) / 0,1kg`? I think I don't get the `- K` part of this multiplication...

Comment: @ojek, that's not a minus sign, it's a hyphen. With velocities you can say "meters per second", but if you had meters TIMES seconds, one might call it a meter-second. That's not a minus sign, that's a hyphen in the English language sense.

Comment: It's still not *necessary* to convert to kelvin, though I would indeed recommend it in (nearly) all calculations involving temperatures. However, it is perfectly alright to multiply two different units. Units of $\text{kg}\cdot\text{K}$ are not incorrect in any way, though you might have a harder time interpreting them. There are only problems if you were to attempt to add or subtract quantities that have different dimensions.

Comment: (So units of $\text{kg}\cdot\ ^{\circ}\text{C}$ are fine as well, though of course kelvin is preferred, as stated before.)

Comment: @NeuroFuzzy: Thanks a lot! That clears everything. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite your expression as:
$\frac{.04 \times 90 \times \text{kg}\ \times ^{\circ}\text{C} \ + \ .06\times50\times \text{kg} \times ^{\circ} \text{C}}{0.1\text{kg}}$. You now have the same units, $\text{kg} \times ^{\circ}\text{C}$, for the two numbers in your numerator and denominator, so you can just add them together to get:
$\frac{6.6 \times \text{kg}\times ^{\circ}\text{C}}{.1\text{kg}} = 66 ^{\circ}\text{C}$.